# In the Youtube API for iPhone SDK, I'm trying to get the videoID of each search result. I'm getting an error every time though, what should I do?

Tags: iphone, search, youtube-api

This is my code:

```
  // Create a service object for executing queries
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
// Services which do not require sign-in may need an API key from the
// API Console
service.APIKey = @"AIzaSyD9pvsUtnegJvwv5z5XrBO5vFTBVpErYN8";
// Create a query
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id"];
query.maxResults = 50;
query.q = @"hiking boots";
//query.country = @"US";
// Execute the query
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                   if (error == nil) {
                                       GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;


                                       // iteration of items and subscript access to items.
                                       for (GTLYouTubeSearchResult *item in products) {

                                           //NSLog(@"%@",item.identifier); - THIS WORKS, BUT GIVES ME THE WHOLE IDENTIFIER, I JUST WANT THE VIDEO ID
                                           NSLog(@"%@",item.identifier.videoId);
                                       }
                                   }else{
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                   }
                               }];
```

If you'll notice the comment above my first NSLog, I'm able to print out a number of things without any issue. But if I try to print out a property of item.identifier, the app crashes completely.
The crash log is this:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLYouTubeVideo videoId]: unrecognized selector sent
```

Now, item.identifier is a GTLYouTubeResourceId, so why is it thinking that I'm trying to get properties from a GTLYoutubeVideo???

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try accessing the JSON of the identifier object directly. There appears to be a "videoId" value in there. 
like this:

> [item.identifier.JSON objectForKey:@"videoId"]

Answer (score 0):

> Now, item.identifier is a `GTLYouTubeResourceId`

Apparently, it isn't.

> so why is it thinking that I'm trying to get properties from a `GTLYoutubeVideo`???

<s>Because you wrote three consecutive question marks.</s> Because it's a `GTLYoutubeVideo` instance, in fact. Sorry, C (and thus Objective-C) is not a very type-safe language. You can declare objects to be of some type, and they can be assigned a pointer to some other kind of object at runtime.

Here, I suspect you either misread something in the documentation or there's a bug in the client library or this is a weird memory management error, but one thing is sure: the runtime is always right.

Comment: Alright, then: Why can't I do   item.statistics , if i do that, it tells me it can't do [GTLYoutubeSearchResult statistics]?

Comment: @userXXX Your problem is that the declaration doesn't match the object's actual run-time type. And the compiler doesn't know anything about the run-time type.